# How to check if element is on screen

Tags: python, selenium

I have a case when I need to find out what button is displayed now. I try it in this way first
{please don't mind on my helper functions. I thinks you can easy understand that Ui.find_el it is almost the same as driver.find_element_by....}:

```
if Ui.find_el(link.AuthorPopupNodes.LOGIN_EMAIL).is_displayed():
    pass
else:
    if Ui.find_el(link.HeaderNodes.LOGOUT_BUTTON).is_displayed():
        self.log_out()
    Ui.wait_for_element(link.HeaderNodes.LOGIN_BUTTON, "Timeout: Wait for Login button!")
    Ui.click_el(link.HeaderNodes.LOGIN_BUTTON)
```

But then it start to fall errors that driver can't find element, so I cover it by try but it didn't work for me too.

```
try:
    if Ui.find_el(link.AuthorPopupNodes.LOGIN_EMAIL).is_displayed():
        pass
    else:
        if Ui.find_el(link.HeaderNodes.LOGOUT_BUTTON).is_displayed():
            self.log_out()
        Ui.wait_for_element(link.HeaderNodes.LOGIN_BUTTON, "Timeout: Wait for Login button!")
        Ui.click_el(link.HeaderNodes.LOGIN_BUTTON)
except:
    pass
```

For example if first IF fails, than it get out from try and I need to check if there is LOGOUT button. HIs it possible to check for element without try but also without selenium errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch [specific selenium errors](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#module-selenium.common.exceptions), for example:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, ElementNotVisibleException

try:
    Ui.find_el(link.AuthorPopupNodes.LOGIN_EMAIL)
except (NoSuchElementException, ElementNotVisibleException):
    try:
        Ui.find_el(link.HeaderNodes.LOGOUT_BUTTON)
        self.log_out()
    except (NoSuchElementException, ElementNotVisibleException):   
        pass

    Ui.wait_for_element(link.HeaderNodes.LOGIN_BUTTON, "Timeout: Wait for Login button!")
    Ui.click_el(link.HeaderNodes.LOGIN_BUTTON)
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand that I need to use try like IF.